# how to convert lua table to golang map[string]string

Tags: go, lua

the following is lua table return value, it likes array:

```
[clientID abcde state 1 activity 8 deviceType 4 seq 1]
```

[image]

I want to covert to golang  map[string]string like here:

```
{
"clientId": "abcde",
"state": "1",
"activity": "8",
"deviceType": "4",
"seq": "1"}
```

how to do ?

Comment: use lua script in golang，“[clientID abcde state 1 activity 8 deviceType 4 seq 1]” is return value.  Now, I want to convert to map[string]string

Answer (score 0):

That's one way I think(an example):

```
func convert() {
    var arr = []string{"k1", "v1", "k2", "v2", "k3", "v3", "k4", "v4", "k5", "v5", "k6", "v6"}
    var res = map[string]string{}
    for i := 0; i < len(arr)/2; i++ {
        val := arr[i*2 : i*2+2]
        res[val[0]] = val[1]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine

```
func convert(kvs []string) map[string]string{
    if len(kvs)%2 != 0 {
        panic("num of kvs item should be even")
    }

    result := make(map[string]string, len(kvs)/2)
    for i := 0; i < len(kvs)-1; i+=2 {
        result[kvs[i]] = kvs[i+1]
    }
    return result
}
```